# Rails: Pass a parameter to a render js function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my controller

```
...
..
render :js => "window.location = '/bar/ready'", :locals => { :foo => "foo" } 
..
...
```

I want the `<% foo %>` variable and I want to access it in my HTML page.

but I cant seem to access it, as `<%= params.inspect %>` returns

```
{"controller"=>"bar", "action"=>"ready"}
```

So how can I pass the variable in my HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar. Late, but I finally manage to do it doing:

```
render :js => "window.location = #{your_path(:foo => 'foo').to_json}"
```

And then parse json data in your view